# No access to network drive

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm having trouble enabling permission to a network drive. When I try to access it through My Computer by entering `\\serverName\d$`, I'm prompted to enter my user name and password, but it doesn't accept it and it keeps me asking for it (without throwing any message). If I try to access it using my admin username and password, it works. The permissions for the D drive in my server for Everyone is set like:

- Traverse folder/execute file
- List folder/read data
- Read attributes
- Read extended attributes
- Read permissions

I need all users to be able to access this driver. Am I missing something?

Comment: Guest account enabled on the server?

Comment: What OS-**version** is the server? And workstation?

Comment: @Rik: The application server is Windows Server 2008 R2 and the workstation is Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share) the "administrative shares" (which `\\servername\d$` is) are no longer available for "normal"-users from Vista and higher and can only be accessed by "true" local admin user.

> By default, Windows Vista and later use User Account Control (UAC) to enforce security. One of UAC features denies administrative rights to user who access network shares on the local computer over a network, unless the accessing user is registered on a Windows domain. It is possible to disable UAC remote restrictions.

So it might be possible if you switch off UAC but i wouldn't advice that. There could also be some registry hacks around to give "Everyone" access but i would also advice against those.

---

Also from Microsoft [kb947232](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947232):

> By default, Windows Vista and newer versions of Windows prevent local accounts from accessing administrative shares through the network.

---

So i wouldn't advice using the administrative share actively.

If you want to share the **whole** `D`-drive you should re-share it as a separate share. (i.e. `\\servername\data`). (You could of course also just share **one folder** with all your files)

[image]